# How to display largest total first in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a small query that sums the totals of columns, is there a way I can ORDER BY ASC so that the result displays the rows with the biggest total first.

My query is:

```
select
sum(SeqID0101 = 1) as SeqID0101,
sum(SeqID0102 = 1) as SeqID0102,
sum(SeqID0103 = 1) as SeqID0103,
sum(SeqID0104 = 1) as SeqID0104,
sum(SeqID0105 = 1) as SeqID0105,
sum(SeqID0106 = 1) as SeqID0106,
sum(SeqID0107 = 1) as SeqID0107,
sum(SeqID0108 = 1) as SeqID0108,
sum(SeqID0109 = 1) as SeqID0109,
sum(SeqID0110 = 1) as SeqID0110
from 
PH001_Hist
```

EDIT

Hi and thanks for your replies.

I am using the code below to produce tow columns, 1 with the name of the field, 2 with the data content. This works as I require. But when the query sums the content of the fields I need to order the result to display the largest field content first.

Example:

Fieldname   FieldData

SEQID0101 -  8

SeqID0108 -  6

SeqID0103 -  2

and so no.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($FailedList);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($row as $k => $v)
echo '<tr><td>'.$k.'</td><td >'.$v.'</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

I just can't get the code right to produce the require result.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Er, that would be DESC !?!? But your problem is really one of poor (i.e. non-normalized) design.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit of a pedant, but the query you've shown only produces a one-row result set. It's not clear what you mean by "rows with the biggest total first." Can you please edit your question, and pay attention to the distinction between "rows" and "columns."

Comment: exactly @OllieJones thats what I was about to ask, DCJones you are not doing any group by and it will be just single row so why you need order by ?

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
  ORDER BY GREATEST(SeqID0101,SeqID0102,SeqID0103,SeqID0104 , .....) DESC
```